# Unable to view all matching results with Typeahead/Bloodhound

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-typeahead, bloodhound

I am using Typeahead/Bloodhoud for a company search and the autocomplete section is not showing enough matches.

**----------  Search ----------**

[image]

I should see at least 5 results since the limit is 5.

**----------  Ajax Response ----------**

[image]

**Typeahead JS**

```
companies = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: function(d) {
        return Bloodhound.tokenizers.nonword(d.id);
    },
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.nonword,
    remote: 'access/companies?q=%QUERY'
});
companies.initialize();
$('#companySearch').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    source: companies.ttAdapter(),
    updater: selectCompany
});
```

How can I ensure that all of my results appear as expected?  I've been digging through the documentation/source code looking for options I must've overlooked and have been struggling to come up with any.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of Typeahead?  I don't think it takes a updater option any more?

Comment: @joeljoeljoel I believe so... v0.10.5 The updater option is worked as expected for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I simply wanted to use typeahead as my bootstrap-styled autocomplete menu.  That means that I didn't want to leave it up to my JS to do any kind of logic for matching results.  There's an undocumented (at the time of this post) configuration setting that you can use called `matcher` which allows you to customize how typeahead filters results.  I simply overwrote it so that it returned every result.

```
$('#companySearch').typeahead({
    highlight: true,
    minLength: 1,
    source: companies.ttAdapter(),
    updater: selectCompany,
    matcher: function (t) {
        return t;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a 'displayKey' within the typeahead call.
Displaykey should be 'name' in your case.
Something like this:

```
// instantiate the typeahead UI
$( '#companySearch').typeahead(null, {
  displayKey: 'name',
  source: companies.ttAdapter()
});
```